# Determine CD/DVD burn date

Tags: dvd, cd, burning

How can I determine the date when a CD/DVD was written?

I have already tried Disc info in Nero4Linux and `cdrecord -v dev=xxx -toc`, but unfortunately none of them gave me the answer.

I know there might be a difference between the real burn date and the date the burning software actually puts on the disk; the indicated date is just fine.

Answer (score 0):

here is a link, where you could search for further details:

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-cdburn/index.html

I would read man of `wodim`, `cdrecord` and else man-pages ... (am deaf) - perhaps
command `saytime` can help when you combine it with mount of `/media/cdrom`?

Comment: As far as I see these tools don't have such option (or I couldn't find it). I tried `cdrdao disk-info`, `wodim -v -toc` and `wodim -v -atip`. None of these has displayed the burn date.